# Disable all sound permanently

Tags: sound

I've got a lab for high school students, and I'd like to disable audio altogether on the lab computers.

Any suggestions? I've been looking at `alsa force-unload`, but that only kills processes that are currently using the sound card. When I reload the browser and hit YouTube, sound comes back.

Basically, I want to unload sound from the kernel ...but easier than that.

Comment: Don't if it would work but would think if you disable/delete or blacklisted the audio/sound drivers in kernel. Would need to be root to disable/enable.  Easiest way would be to set sound to mute in settings, but anybody can do/undo that.  I am not good enough to explain how.

Comment: Maybe put `blacklist snd` in a file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-snd.conf`? AFAIK all the snd modules depend on it (and it depends on soundcore -- see `modinfo snd`, so perhaps that's the one to blacklist) and I think it's responsible for loading up the sound cards, so in theory without it you shouldn't have any sound possible (unless someone has `sudo` on `modprobe`). {Argh, you beat me too it!}

Comment: Cut the speaker wire :) KISS

Comment: If desktop computers, unplugging the external speakers is trivial, and unplugging the internal one only slightly more difficult.  Notebooks are a bit more difficult, but not a problem for the mechanically adept.  More difficult is to disable sound except on the rare instances when I actually want it.  To date, my only "solution" is to keep an older computer just for sound (and backups &c).

Comment: Is it possible to disable soundcards in UEFI? My PC allows that.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff or plug in a dummy headphone plug.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All right, so blacklisting the sound related modules worked. Thanks to this post:

http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/disabling-sound-kernel-modules-debian-ubuntu-gnu-linux-servers/

The details of the fix:

edit `/etc/modprobe.d/snd-blacklist.conf` and add these entries (from a Dell standalone pc with 18.04)

```
blacklist soundcore
blacklist snd
blacklist snd_pcm
blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi
blacklist snd_hda_codec_realtek
blacklist snd_hda_codec_generic
blacklist snd_hda_intel
blacklist snd_hda_codec
blacklist snd_hda_core
blacklist snd_hwdep
blacklist snd_timer
```

Answer (score 16):

A hardware solution: insert a mini-jack connector in the sound output port, but *only* a connector, without any wire or speaker on it. This has worked for me since the 80's to silence the Mac's otherwise beautiful power-on ding.

Comment: As a more permanent (and gross solution), put hot glue in the jack. I don't know what OP's use-case is but if the problem is kids plugging their own things in (for whatever reason) then this answer won't be enough.

Comment: @CaptainMan Hot glue alone won't make the computer route audio to the jack. But you could glue in a jack.

Comment: @Solomonoff's Secret good point. I wasn't thinking about built-in speakers.

Comment: I used to use this trick in the OP's situation (a lab of computers in a high school class).  Of course, I was a student in the class, and was booting up a MacPlus so I could play Risk in drafting class.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be removing the alsa drivers, i.e.:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa
```

Comment: That could easily be reversed accidentally by some later installation command, right?

Comment: I guess everything can be reversed later. This is just a quick solution for OP's problem, not a "cripple my sound forever" kind of answer.

Comment: Sure, but my point is this will _quite likely_ be reversed _inadvertently_, namely when installing some package which happens to depend on `alsa`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work. Edit the file `/etc/pulse/client.conf`

Change the line:

```
; autospawn = yes
```

to

```
autospawn = no
```

And

```
; daemon-binary = /usr/bin/pulseaudio
```

to

```
daemon-binary = /usr/bin/pulseaudio
```

Reboot.

Comment: Every user could override the settings in `/etc/pulse/cliet.conf` with his/her own settings in `~/.config/pulse/client.conf`, please take a look at `man pulse-client.conf`.

Comment: So after this change, audio is still playing -- there are just no audio controls any more so volume is 100% . Thanks for the suggestion though. I think alsa just took over when pulse went away.