# disable audio permanently

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio

I'm running 18.0.4 LTS on hardware whose only audio out is an HDMI port, to a monitor without speakers.  Because the audio is inaudible, I'd like to not waste resources playing it.  How should I configure this, in a way that survives reboots?

On older versions of Ubuntu, uninstalling or disabling PulseAudio can break other things.  I'd like to still be able to view websites, play videos silently, etc.

`man pulse-daemon.conf` suggests a hack: set `fail=true` and misspell a command in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.  But that might be more for per-user mode instead of system mode, whatever those mean.

A collection of related hacks is listed in the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176426/disable-all-sound-permanently), but those are for a classroomful whereas I'm the only user of this hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. You can blacklist the kernel modules that relate to audio, therefore the user-space software will not have access to those resources.

To find which kernel modules are loaded for your system configuration, run

```
lsmod | grep snd
```

The `snd` and `snd-hda-intel` kernel modules are likely the ones that all the rest depend on. Therefore, if you blacklist those, there will be no audio. The specific kernel module for HDMI audio is `snd_hda_codec_hdmi`.

To create the blacklist file, launch a text editor and create a new file.

```
gedit --new-document admin:///etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-all-audio.conf
```

Then, add in there

```
blacklist snd
blacklist snd-hda-intel
```

I would be interested to see whether PulseAudio will launch when there are no audio kernel modules. Please report back on this.

Comment: After I played a few videos with ffmpeg and through firefox, `top` reported only one process, `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog`, and syslog had only one entry, `[pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files`.  So it looks like fewer resources are being used!